# ProTran Transfer Switch has both lines hot and breaker is off

Tags: electrical, electrical-panel, transfer-switch

I have a Reliance controls 6 circuit transfer switch that I've been using for a while without any issues offsetting electric with my "solar generator". Today I want to do some maintenance and I shut off the breakers in the load center that go to the transfer switch. The solar generator was still on with AC output producing electric for the circuits that I have wired. My AC sensor was beeping indicating the lines from the load center breakers to the switch are hot. Why is this? I figured if the breakers are turned off then the line would be off and only the lines from the transfer switch to the circuits would be hot. I checked this for all six circuits and the red cord goes from the breaker to the transfer switch and all red cords were hot. The black cords go to the circuits and those were hot as well as I expected.

Comment: Photos please. ...